# Create HostingEnvironment instance with WebRootPath

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core-3.1

I'm migrating from `netcore2.1` to `netcore3.1`. I have a service where I need to create an IServiceProvider and inject `IWebHostEnvironment` (I used to inject `IHostingEnvironment` in netcore2.1). The code used to just create a new `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.HostingEnvironment` instance but that class doesn't contain `WebRootPath` anymore. I fetched git repo and tried to look for implementations of IWebHostEnvironment but it seems that the only implementation is internal to aspnetcore which is of no use.

Is there a possibility to create an instance of IWebHostEnvironment somehow?

Daniel

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It would be awesome if you could share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do? That way we could probably suggest an alternative for the new version of the code.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The class is internal for a reason - there's no valid scenario for an app's code to modify that class. Are you trying to *mock* the location of the web root during testing? Use [WebApplicationFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Or serve files from a different path? That's explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#serve-files-outside-of-web-root): pass the path as an option to `UseStaticFiles`

Answer (score -1):

Hi You can access WebRoot Path using in Core 3.1

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
          private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnv;

           public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnv)
           {
             _hostingEnv = hostingEnv;
           }

          private Void GetWebRoot()
          {
             var webRootPath = _hostingEnv.WebRootPath;
          }
     }
```

Can you try this, upvote if it helps

Comment: Hey - as I wrote, I need to CREATE an intsance of some class that implements IWebHostEnvironment interface, not use DI for that.

Comment: Then why you don't you use the reference to IWebHostEnvironment from DI and pass it into a constructor of the object that you want to create?

Comment: I still don't get how the object implementing IWebHostEnvironment is created.

Comment: Only possible way if you can Implement IWebHostEnvironment in another class, but I don't know what problems, you may face. best is just use DI , instead of re inventing the wheel. Best practice is use DI

Comment: @Aranha Well you want to manually want to create an object of class A that uses IWebHostEnvironment. So call the constructor of A?

Comment: @Aranha you didn't explain what you want to do. The answer made the (quite logical) assumption that you want to use that property. You don't need to implement that interface, unless you want to *mock* the path during unit/integration testing. Is that what you want? Or are you trying to use a different web root?